# Android Webview Auto Redirect when click a Button inside a Webview's page

Tags: android, webview

I have a Webview activity which contains the payment method which finally brings up the finish button.

Currently when the button is clicked finish, Webview only displays the completed view which needs me to click on App bar back or click the Back navigation button manually to exit from that Webview.

Is it possible when I click a button inside that WebView bring me automatically to some Activity I want?
Because, I think using `onPageFinished()` won't work because the method will be triggered on all page

Comment: I am not sure, but I think what you need is a JS Bridge.

Comment: Yeah I think so, set the proper code in the web then connect it via JS to the Android's you mean right? But the web itself is a payment gateway, not mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this method inside `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {}` to solve my problem

```
            @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("https://your-designated-url.com/")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                getActivity().finish();
            } else {
                pDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }
```